# Typescript: Intellisense autocomplete - custom function as deeply nested object property, that infers it's argument type from the object property

Tags: typescript, intellisense

Basically, I have this type

```js
type X = {
  a: {
    b?: string;
    c?: string;
    d: {
      e:{
        f:{
          g?: boolean
        }
      }
    };
  };
};

// and a helper
const as = <T,>(arg: T):T => arg;
```

and I need to be able to create an object, in the shape of X
where all properties, on all levels of nesting, are replaced by:

```js
as({
    // autocomplete here with actual object property
    // unless it's not an object
})

// like so

const x = as<X>({
  a: as({
    b: as("some string"),
    d: as({
      e: as({
        f: as({
          g: as(false)
        })
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I got it working to a degree, but at more than 2 levels of nesting, the autocomplete no longer ...autocompletes

Please refer to the [Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=34&pln=23&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgzgeQEYCsIGNgB4AqA%20KAXihyggA9gIA7AEzigEEAnZgQxCzepDwCgogqAH4oAMzYAbOBAFCAXCTKUa9KABE2VOYNETpsoVEWkKVOgwD2qDMB0iowZgFdDC8VJkBuPn1CQoADlA3AJiQMtqQOdJSTYkSQhQn19-aABlXAAaACUiEjDYRBtMLGDQgjNVBidXe1EAb3sjQQBtAGkoAEtqKABrCBBLMRIAXWFFTJwO0dz%20FqgAX3tFAAoANylXEyyoZktLYEUcgEoiAhwUvjFnakwuyKg4UNW4SdCT9-wmgEhmCGAzmYvTgPmWfHQkTgwCgbAYxGyeFWbGYAHMTJ9SIQCCjUSk0lAABr5JqCNiKUlCJATJ5OHp4%20zoGnQ5j0nxGWgU5pkeSUhZiXncoyomlIA6JbhCpbc5ZGRbspZglKQ6jQqAgfLPQlIynkvlQTn6wQQQULQQCo0tAD0Vqelg8zDtUFRB1oUsE6KgGyyzDO2Kg6ylspawcEweWixOvl8KrV5E1WG1q0pNudh1hzmAlkhAFswIkqFAABYQf5ycmwuDJ%20ypkv-RwHeycyvVhap6j2nOWetsTPZyx5gsQXZgfaQZigYtwqBICA0RzgCC0KA57jOKSSEDck0ts42ouWSTL4AlleWZwyKCWdalqAAAzhqxOd4AdG-ujCZBAczV7T0xLeJ7QLQEBwF0-zHouuy3MAXSxOq56wpg66xBq0IojCIHoHErLUKijinmI1AAOQMLi9iRnIlGRkAA) for a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: So there's no compiler error or type safety issue, right? It's just about autocomplete?  You might want to put "autocomplete" in the title then.  I don't have much of an insight into what's going on here, but it might be helpful for the title to highlight the nature of the issue so that any TS IntelliSense/autocomplete gurus out there might be more drawn to it ‍♂️

Comment: [Seems fine to me](https://tsplay.dev/wX7QDW). What exactly is the issue?

Comment: It's not an autocomplete issue actually, because even if autocompletion works for the first 2 levels, object property types are not being inferred correctly. I mean, you can write the `as` argument manually, but you have no type inference, and because the return type is what you feed it, and matches the root, TS will not complain, unless you write an argument that fails to match the root schema

Comment: I assume that some sort of inverse mapping is needed there, but unsure how to do it. Also, the issue is clearly visible in the last code fragment in the playground link.

Comment: And i repeat, I don't think it's an autocomplete issue, because if it's not working in the playground... unless the playground uses the same Intellisense engine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So... with the help of somebody from typescript's Discord community, i got it working.

Final working example:

```js
type IsObject<T> = T extends Array<any>
    ? false
    : T extends Date
    ? false
    : T extends object
    ? true
    : false;

type BuiltInFn = "someFn";

type NullableUndefinedOrEmptyUnion = "nullable" | "undefined" | "emptyString";

type Primitive<T> = T extends string
    ? "string"
    : T extends boolean
    ? "boolean"
    : T extends number
    ? "number"
    : never;

type NN<T> = NonNullable<T>;

type S<T, R = T> = IsObject<NN<T>> extends true
    ? {
          [K in keyof T]?: IsObject<NN<T[K]>> extends false
              ? S<NN<T[K]>, R>
              :
                    | (<XX extends S<NN<T[K]>, R>>(
                          value: XX | undefined,
                          root: R
                      ) => boolean | void)
                    | (<XX extends S<NN<T[K]>, R>>(
                          value: <YY extends S<NN<T[K]>, R>>(value: YY, root: R) => boolean | void,
                          root: R
                      ) => XX | void);
      }
    :
          | (<XX extends NN<T>>(
                value: Primitive<XX> extends never
                    ? BuiltInFn | undefined
                    : Primitive<XX> | undefined,
                root: R
            ) => XX | void)
          | (<XX extends NN<T>>(
                value: <YY extends NN<T>>(value: YY, root: R) => boolean | void,
                root: R
            ) => XX | void);

function s<T>(s: S<T, T>): S<T, T> {
    return s;
}

type A<T> = T extends (value: infer U, root: infer UU) => infer Z ? U : never;

function as<T>(arg: A<T>, ...opts: Array<BuiltInFn | NullableUndefinedOrEmptyUnion>): NN<T> {
    return arg as any;
}

type X = {
    a?: {
        b?: string;
        c?: number;
        d: {
            nested?: {
                e: {
                    f: boolean;
                };
                g: {
                    x: number;
                };
            };
        };
    };
};

const x = s<X>({
    a: as({
        d: as({
            nested: as({
                e: as({
                    f: as("boolean"),
                }),
            }),
        }),
        b: as("string"),
    }),
});
```

Now you can use a custom function that can receive 3 types as an argument:

- the object property itself (if prop === object) with optional params
- an anonymous function which takes 2 arguments (the object property itself, and the root object)
- if the param is not an object, a string literal which represents the type of the param, or an anonymous function as described above

And... everything is typed no matter how deep

Beautiful!